# How to log to file and console at the same time with logging?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I need to log data to file and also to console. I setup it like this:

```
# set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level    = logging.INFO,
                    format   ='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt  ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler(dir + '/log.log'), logging.StreamHandler()]
                    )
```

Then i add data like this: `logging.info('Server started')`. In console i see the text, but file is empty. If I delete tgis file python creates new one, but still it is empty.

Comment: `logging.basicConfig` dose not use `handlers` argument. So your code does not work as you expected.

Comment: i found it does, actually, use the `handlers` argument.  and quite nicely, at that.  this is how i configured my logger to write to file and console simultaneously: but i am running Python 3.10.

Answer (score 11):

Its just a case of setting of multiple handlers for the same error level.

Remove basicConfig line and do something similar to below

See this example of how to do this:

```
import logging

log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) %(message)s', 
                                  datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

#File to log to
logFile = 'C:\\Temp\\log'

#Setup File handler
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logFile)
file_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#Setup Stream Handler (i.e. console)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#Get our logger
app_log = logging.getLogger('root')
app_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#Add both Handlers
app_log.addHandler(file_handler)
app_log.addHandler(stream_handler)

#Write some Data
while True:
    app_log.info("data")
```